# django file opens locally but fails in server

Tags: django, django-file-upload

What I wanted to achieve was for a user to upload a file through a form, lets say profile picture,
My aim is to take that file, send it through imgbb's api and get the image url to store for use in my template later. 
I was able to achieve this with the piece of code below, that works locally(Windows) but as soon as I push to my production server(pythonanywhere in this case), the code fails.

```
# CODE: 
def testingpage(request):
    image = ''
    url = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pic = request.FILES['image']
        url = upload_to_bb(request, pic)
        if url is not None:
            from django.contrib import messages
            messages.info(request, 'Uploaded Successfully')

    return render(request, 'test.html', {'image': url})


def upload_to_bb(request, pic):
    import os
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
    import base64
    import requests

    base_url = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(pic.name, pic)
    file_path = f'{base_url}\media\{filename}'
    apikey = settings.IMGBB_API_KEY
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        url = "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload"
        payload = {
            "key": apikey,
            "image": base64.b64encode(file.read()),
        }
        r = requests.post(url, payload)
        js = r.json()
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = js['data']
            file.close()
            os.remove(file_path)
            return data['image']['url']
        else:
            file.close()
            os.remove(file_path)
            from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
            raise ValidationError("An error occurred processing the image")
    return None
```

the culprit is this line of code

```
file_path = f'{base_url}\media\{filename}'
```

On local windows server:
It returns

```
C:\Users\Sammy\PycharmProjects\kegites\media\WIN_20211209_15_41_37_Pro.jpg
```

on pythonanywhere, I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError at /

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/kegitesclub/kegites\\media\\WIN_20211209_15_41_36_Pro_3afnrPi.jpg'
```

on heroku , I get:

```
No such file or directory: '/app\\media\\WIN_20211209_15_41_37_Pro.jpg'
```

Is it something to do with linux, that these servers are or is it something else, perhaps a Django limitation?, or can you suggest a better approach to reach end result?

Any help would be appreciated

StackTrace for pythonanywhere:

[image: The stacktrace, it displays weirdly with copy/paste]

Image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/quXPI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have system agnostic paths (between Windows and  Linux environments) use `os.path.join` or even better `pathlib` to build them.

```py
file_path = os.path.join(base_url, 'media', filename)
```

or in case of `pathlib`

```py
base_url = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

and then

```py
file_path = base_url / 'media' / filename
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing this line from this

```
file_path = f'{base_url}\media\{filename}'
```

to this

```
file_path = f'{base_url}/media/{filename}'
```

and test it in the server

Comment: This works too, I just prefer @Filip's answer, It's more professional :)